# term inside emacs:: how to turn "word wrap" off

Tags: bash, emacs

In setting up my personal Linux command line development environment, I want to use term inside emacs b/c then I can switch to 'line mode' and copy/paste the output into any other buffer.

However, when I run mysql inside term inside emacs, the pretty sql tables still word wrap according to the width of that emacs window :(. I was hoping that emacs would truncate the bash output.

Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

toggle-truncate-lines is on, so "word wrap" is off, but the problem is that before emacs even does anything with the text, the underlying bash process itself manually adds newlines to wrap text according to the width it's told it's using. That's at least how it acts. toggling truncate lines on/off doesn't change anything for me in the *term* buffer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you probably want is "M-x toggle-truncate-lines".  That toggles between wrapping or requiring you to scroll right and left to see the entire line.

Comment: This is actually a way better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to add something to the sql hook to turn off the wrapping:

```
(add-hook 'sql-interactive-mode-hook '(lambda () (toggle-truncate-lines 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Emacs might be setting the `COLUMNS` environment variable to indicate when the shell should wrap lines. Try setting it to a very large value and see if that helps.

I have no idea what other things this will break though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Meta-X auto-fill-mode
```

This will toggle auto-fill mode and stop the line wrap.

Answer (score 1):

The function `term--unwrap-visible-long-lines` is called by `term-reset-size` whenever the window is resized and appears to be responsible for the unwanted wrapping, and is not configurable.  I hack this by advising the function to fix the wrapped width to a large value.

```
(defun my-prevent-term-unwrap (original-function height width)
  (apply original-function (list height 10000)))

(advice-add 'term-reset-size :around 'my-prevent-term-unwrap)
```